# 2000 Ford Taurus ABS reluctor ring grinding on lower ball joint

Tags: ford, suspension, abs, taurus, ball-joint

My Taurus started to make a grinding noise in the front. When I looked at it I could see the ABS reluctor ring was grinding on the lower ball joint. My plan is to replace the axles/reluctor rings, but I was wondering if this may be from the struts weakening or something else.

Comment: Possible bad wheel bearing.

Comment: @Marty I concur with Moab.  You are going to want to get this fixed pronto.  Delay on this fix just generates more bad results and $$.

Comment: Jack up the front end, try to move the wheel in all directions and feel for play.  if there is play, look where it is coming from.